# How to view filesystem in Eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse, file, view, aptana, eclipse-pdt

I've been using Aptana standalone for a few months. I do a lot of quick fixes on various servers via Windows network share, and the Aptana File view is perfect for that.

Aptana has a "File view" that allowed me to navigate my entire filesystem and quickly open files to make edits.

I'm being pressured into using "proper" Eclipse PDT again (I need the Zend debug & preview capability that Aptana just doesn't handle) but I still need to be able to do my quick edits too.

I've looked and looked, but I can't figure out how to do open a network share and browse it in Eclipse - unless I build a project for each folder I open. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you can get plugin to do that

[RSE](http://download.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm/updates/2.0/) seems to be able to handle ftp, after for windows share I don't really know but I am pretty sure you can find something.

Also you can install aptana in PDT that's would probably be the best solution for you since you are used to aptana.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks RageZ. 

RSE doesn't seem to play nice with windows shares - insists on details of a Linux setup. 

Installing Aptana on Eclipse gave me the best of both worlds - my boss is happy because he sees an Eclipse logo, and I'm happy using the enhanced File View functionality. Good Call! (now if I can work out how to get the Debugger working....)

Comment: Your boss is an eclipse fan ???? personaly I don't use aptana anymore I moved my box to Linux so I can mount FTP and ssh and window has they are on my machine. I am using Zend studio but the interface is not responsive has I wished it would be ...

Comment: For the debugger it is not difficult what is your server wamp? Linux box ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck in windoze hell. I use a Win XP pc, talking over a windoze network to wimp servers. I'd love to use Linux at work (I do at home) but our IS guys are MS thru and thru. I just installed Zend Server on my pc, with Apache. Once I get some time to figure out how to make Eclipse / APtana use those to preview / debug, I'll look deeper. For now, at least I can still work, so thanks.